# gradle refresh failed: address already in use

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, gradle

Whenever I want to start a project in Android Studio, I have this error:

> Gradle 'TestProject' project refresh failed 
>   Error:Address already in use: Cannot bind

Until 2 days ago it worked perfect.

Log looks like this:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:43)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:40)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.getCommunicator(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:153)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.reservePort(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:145)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:79)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:67)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.readFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:36)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.get(SimpleStateCache.java:40)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.get(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.getAll(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.getIdle(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:77)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:123)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:132)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:117)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:190)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:105)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:107)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:96)
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:97)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:396)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:251)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:304)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:38)
    ... 30 more
2016-02-02 11:58:25,845 [  39707]   INFO - .BaseProjectImportErrorHandler - Failed to import Gradle project at 'C:/TestGradle' 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:188)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$300(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:367)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:339)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:230)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
    at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:43)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:40)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.getCommunicator(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:153)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.locklistener.DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.reservePort(DefaultFileLockContentionHandler.java:145)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:79)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager.lock(DefaultFileLockManager.java:67)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.OnDemandFileAccess.readFile(OnDemandFileAccess.java:36)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.SimpleStateCache.get(SimpleStateCache.java:40)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.get(FileIntegrityViolationSuppressingPersistentStateCacheDecorator.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.getAll(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.registry.PersistentDaemonRegistry.getIdle(PersistentDaemonRegistry.java:77)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:123)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:132)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:117)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:190)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:105)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:83)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind0(TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:107)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:96)
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.bind(TwoStacksPlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:97)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.bind(DatagramSocket.java:396)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:251)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.<init>(DatagramSocket.java:304)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.FileLockCommunicator.<init>(FileLockCommunicator.java:38)
    ... 30 more
2016-02-02 11:58:25,845 [  39707]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Address already in use: Cannot bind 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Address already in use: Cannot bind
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:457)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:158)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:350)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:373)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:339)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:230)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)

2016-02-02 11:58:25,845 [  39707]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2016-02-02 11:58:25,845 [  39707]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Address already in use: Cannot bind

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2016-02-02 11:58:25,845 [  39707]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'TestGradle' failed: Address already in use: Cannot bind

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2016-02-02 11:58:26,328 [  40190]   INFO - penapi.project.DumbServiceImpl - Dumb mode not permitted in modal environment; see DumbService.allowStartingDumbModeInside documentation.
 Current modality: ModalityState:com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog[dialog0,542,165,836x710,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,APPLICATION_MODAL,title=Project Structure,defaultCloseOperation=DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=,rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
 all permissions: {} 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.scheduleCacheUpdate(DumbServiceImpl.java:160)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.queueTask(DumbServiceImpl.java:85)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.runSymbolActivity(OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.java:142)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.rebuildSymbols(OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.java:110)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.rebuildSymbols(OCSymbolTablesBuildingActivity.java:106)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.symbols.symtable.FileSymbolTablesCache$1.buildSettingsChanged(FileSymbolTablesCache.java:151)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:116)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:368)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:355)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:341)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:334)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:42)
    at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$2.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:223)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.buildSettingsChanged(Unknown Source)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.workspace.OCWorkspaceModificationTrackers$4.run(OCWorkspaceModificationTrackers.java:52)
    at com.jetbrains.cidr.lang.workspace.OCWorkspaceModificationTrackers$MyModificationTracker.incModificationCount(OCWorkspaceModificationTrackers.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace$3.run(GradleWorkspace.java:260)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction$1.compute(ReadAction.java:29)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction$1.compute(ReadAction.java:26)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.ReadAction.execute(ReadAction.java:26)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace.updateGradleWorkspace(GradleWorkspace.java:263)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace.access$100(GradleWorkspace.java:87)
    at com.android.tools.ndk.GradleWorkspace$2.run(GradleWorkspace.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
2016-02-02 11:58:26,423 [  40285]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-02-02 11:58:26,423 [  40285]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-02-02 11:58:26,423 [  40285]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2016-02-02 11:58:26,423 [  40285]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s.
```

Comment: Sounds like studio is not able to acquire a lock on some file. Restart your machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem, it was because of my company antivirus (F-Secure) after latest update.

Answer (score -1):

This sometimes happens on windows when you have your hotspot on as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887218/android-studio-gradle-daemon-java-net-bindexception-address-already-in-use-b).

If your OS is windows and you have your hotspot on, try switching it off.

If that fails try restarting your PC.