# Android Studio Gradle Daemon - java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I run the `Gradle project sync` in **Android Studio** (`java 8.0.181`) I get:

`java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind`

But I can't find WHICH address (I assume address is really `port`) is already being used (since none is listed) so I can kill the process there and retry the gradle build.

I can only see the Android Studio process/port in `TCPView`, not anything specific to Gradle.

```
In the Android Studio terminal I have run gradlew --stacktrace:
20:51:56.188 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Please read the following process output to find out more:
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] -----------------------
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:34)
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:151)
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:134)
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:20
5)
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:127)
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:138)
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:92)
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFacto
ry.java:287)
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFacto
ry.java:260)
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:33)
20:51:56.192 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
20:51:56.196 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
20:51:56.196 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
20:51:56.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:
253)
20:51:56.200 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:
182)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]   at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
20:51:56.204 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
20:51:56.208 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
20:51:56.208 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I have checked all the fixes for this online but haven't found the solution!

Comment: I ended up killing Macrium Reflect, which was running as a process, and that worked...until the problem crept up again. Killing processes one by one, doing Invalidate Caches/Restart and even killing Chrome *seems* to have fixed this. Maddening that java doesn't tell you WHICH "address is already in use". Is there a reason it can't find it, perhaps?

Comment: Boy did I become 'comfortable' in dealing with this problem after re-running attempted fixes dozens of times!

Answer (score 6):

Make sure mobile hotspot is switched off on your pc. find solution [here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/67033172684/)

Comment: I'd been trolling google for days until I found this answer. I can't express the level of frustration I am feeling towards Android Studio at this moment! This worked, thanks for the help!

Comment: You sir, are a life saviour

Answer (score 0):

for me, this error occurred only once.
i ended all the running apps.

and

hurray.